# Can jzy3d be used with GEF-based applications?

Tags: plot, charts, swt, eclipse-gef, jzy3d

We are planning to use one of the chart libraries for our Eclipse Application. jzy3d is one of them that seems pretty useful. However, there is no information, whether it could be used with our data providing solutions like GEF for plotting.

Does anyone have an idea about it? Or simply any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, JZY3d can be used with Eclipse applications.

It and its dependencies have been recently added to Eclipse [EBR](https://github.com/eclipse/ebr) making them easier to use in OSGI.

There is also now a JZY3D canvas that uses the JOGL SWT Newt canvas (using SWTChartComponentFactory) avoiding the requirement of the SWT-AWT bridge.